# Route packets via backbone interface

Tags: networking, routes, iptables, packet

I have a general routing question,

we have 2 servers in 2 separate datacenters
they can both talk to each other via em1 interface, but cannot talk to each other via p1p1 interfaces

we have a customer that will connect to NY1's p1p1 interface + port and they should get a reply back from the process thats running that port

the caveat is that the process only runs in Chicago, but the customer is connecting via New York

how can I route the customer request via em1 backbone to Chicago's p1p1 interface, and then hop back the same way to the customer? My envisioned process is below, but I'm wondering if theres a better way to do this?

1. customer tries to connect to process via port 2400 (connecting to NY's p1p1 advertised route)
2. iptables routes the packet over to CH1 em1 interface
3. the packet is then dropped onto CH1 p1p1 interface where the process replys on port 2400
4. packet is sent back via same hops and back out to customer (CH1:p1p1 > CH1:em1 > NY1:em1 > NY1:p1p1 > customer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

figured out how to do this,

need 2 sets of NAT rules. Wrote up the approach here,

https://sites.google.com/site/mrxpalmeiras/linux/iptables-routing#TOC-Connect-to-service-via-backbone-interface

btw, why are people down voting questions? Seriously, why do this?